# DFS locations are not getting deleted in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-neon

I had installed hadoop on my machine and Imported hadoop project in eclipse(Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)) as well and now I am done with hadoop project.now when I try to delete DFS location by clicking on delete button from DFS Right click options,it does not delete it.
Is there any other way to delete this as now I no longer need this.

[image: DFS location issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Project Explorer* view, virtual nodes can be deactivated as follows:

1. In the ***Project Explorer***, click the **view menu** (the triangle top right) and choose ***Filters and Customization...***
2. In the *Filters and Customization* dialog go to the ***Content*** tab and **uncheck** the corresponding **check box**

Alternatively, you can uninstall the plug-in that contributes the customization.